# .htaccess wont rewrite "?id="

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issues with some url rewrite tules that wont rewrite "?id="

Example:   product?id=123  I want to show it like: product/123

I have tried something like this:

```
#first option

#Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product-12.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$1

#second option

#Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product/ipod-nano/12.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$2
```

Comment: Remove the `Rewriting` lines and the second `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Did that, just pasted here wrongly. No result ! : (

Answer (score 0):

You have no flags on your rules

```
# Rewriting product/ipod-nano/12.html to product.php?id=12
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/[-\w]+/(\d+)\.html$ product.php?id=$1 [NS,NE,DPI,L]
```

Comment: That's not enough info for me to help you.

Comment: You say "no result" and "stays same" but you don't describe what *is* happening, and what the same thing is to begin with.